# How to access the value of invoked function in switch statemant

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Consider the following code:

```js
switch (doSomething()) {
    case "1":
        return 1;
    case "2":
        return 2;
    default:
        console.log(RETURNED_VALUE); // I want here to access the value returned from doSomething
}
```

I want to print the value returned from doSomething, without storing it first in a variable. Is it possible? (something similar to `this`)
Thank you

Comment: Nope. You'll need to put it in a variable or argument.

Comment: Your "this" link is not ok.

Comment: @cansu It's not a link, he's referring to the `this` keyword that's used in methods.

Comment: `switch (RETURNED_VALUE = doSomething())`

Comment: This would be a nice feature, but I'm not aware of any language that offers it.

Comment: Add the `switch` to a function and log the result of calling it. `default` would probably be a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good night!

Switch is a conditional structure, like if or ternary operator. It's only a set of instructions, not a object allocated in memory. Because of this, you can't have a "this" feature inside of it. However, if you don't want to store the variable for long time, you can just wrap the switch inside a function, like that:

```
function switchDebug () {
    let value = doSomething(); 
    switch (value) {
        case "1":
            return 1;
        case "2":
            return 2;
        default:
            console.log(value);
    }
}
```

This way, the variable will be cleaned after use of function, because it will be a local scope variable of the function.